# Do we want weekly topic challenges?

Tags: discussion, challenge

A great suggestion from Jon Ericson is to have [Weekly Topic Challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work), these would involve 4 steps:

Step 1: Ask for topic ideas.

Select underrepresented topics, or topics we feel need a boost.

Step 2: Post a challenge.

The challenge would then be posted in meta at a 'usual' time of the week, possibly at the start.  Give a full week for the challenge to play through.

Step 3: Profit!!!! Tally the results.

and

Step 4: Repeat until no more topics are left

What do people think of this idea?  Do we want this?

If so, what topics could we choose?  (1 per week), what dy of the week should we start it?  (We'd have to use UTC time, bearing in mind where people are).

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like an excellent idea. Reminds me of some of the editing competitions on Wikipedia. However, I don't think that *weekly* challenges are appropriate at this stage. The site is rather small with low traffic volume. Maybe we should start with two-week challenges and see how it goes until traffic builds up a bit.

Comment: +1, good idea on making this a biweekly or 'fortnightly' challenge for a smaller site.